# Camera : how to implement camera to the world?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi I am doing project with two Universal robots - UR5 and one mobile robot - Smart. I do not know how to implement the camera as urdf to my world. Could You help me? I attach screen of my scene.

[image: image description]

I would like to upload a camera to this world, but I don't know how to do it. I tried to change the code from the tutorial: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#Camera  but I still have errors in the terminal. Besides, the examples in the tutorials do not show how to insert the camera itself, but how to attach it to a robot, for example. Could someone of you explain me step by step how to do that? I can show you my launch of world and all the urdfs and codes.
Thank You for help! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26230/camera-:-how-to-implement-camera-to-the-world?/) by [Wishram](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/38656/wishram/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here is a simple world with a predefined camera: https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo11/worlds/camera.world

You can find the camera details here: https://github.com/osrf/gazebo_models/blob/master/camera/model.sdf

And, here is how to specify a camera in URDF: http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/UnderstandingPR2URDF#CA-27a380b7379ee7d82de732cd1a9a3490da1152cd_110

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1